# PDEPE nonlinear

Tags: matlab, nonlinear-equations, numerical-modelling, parabolic-pde

I would like to use Matlab's `pdepe` to solve this system:

$$ s_t =(sr)_x + s_{ xx } \\
 r_t =(\frac{ A }{ B }r^2+s)_x + \frac{ A }{ -K } r_{ xx } $$

where $A$, $B$ and $K$ are constants. I need to solve this using MATLAB `pdepe`. The problem is the nonlinear term in my equation: I don't know how to treat the nonlinear part. Boundary and initial conditions are not a problem in that part.

So I've tried to write my PDE in the form that `pdepe` expects:
$$\left(  \begin{array}{c}    1 \\    1 \\ \end{array}\right) \times \frac{ \partial  }{ \partial t }\left(  \begin{array}{c}    s \\    r \\ \end{array}\right)=\left(  \begin{array}{c}    s\frac{ \partial r  }{ \partial x } + r\frac{ \partial s }{ \partial x } \\    2\frac{A}{B}r\frac{ \partial r }{ \partial x } +\frac{ \partial s }{ \partial x }\\ \end{array}\right)+\frac{ \partial  }{ \partial x }\left(  \begin{array}{c}    \frac{ \partial s  }{ \partial x } \\    \frac{A}{-K}\frac{ \partial r }{ \partial x } \\ \end{array}\right)+\left(  \begin{array}{c}    0 \\    0 \\ \end{array}\right) $$

In MATLAB:

```
function [c,f,s] = eqtn(x,t,u,DuDx)

c = 1;

f = ????

s = 0;
```

How to code the function $f$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most straightforward way to write the `eqtn` function is
to define the nonlinear terms as part of the returned `s` vector as follows:

```
f = [DuDx(1); -A/K*DuDx(2)];
s = [u(1)*DuDx(2)+u(2)*DuDx(1); 2*A/B*u(2)*DuDx(2)+DuDx(1)];
```

The question that immediately comes to mind is which terms are 
appropriate to include in the `f` vector compared to `s`?

The PDE system for many physical problems is derived based on the
notion of some quantity being conserved over time. This directly
leads to the idea of a "flux" which is what the `f` vector represents.
That is, `f` has a well-defined meaning in the physical problem.

The definition of `f` is particularly important in defining boundary
conditions. Boundary conditions in `pdepe` take the form

```
p + q*f=0
```

at the right and left ends of the domain. If the boundary condition
has a non-zero `q`, its value depends directly on how `f` is defined.

Comment: If we assume s vector is a part of f vector. What if, in the system they have another function in the first equation. For example, $ s_t =(sr)_x + s_{ xx }+r^2 $   ;
$ r_t =(\frac{ A }{ B }r^2+s)_x + \frac{ A }{ -K }r_{ xx } $  . Is the vector of s still depend on f vector?  or it is possible to add another function ( such as p=[u(1)^2 ; 0] in the matlab code?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question. In general the s vector contains all the spatially-dependent (or constant) terms that are not part of f.

Comment: okay I get it. Thank you Dr for helping me. Now I understand. s vector can contains constant too. Thank you so much!